# Replace accents from lists of foreign words

Tags: list, localization

Do you know if there are any linux programs out there to remove accents from lists of foreign words (in utf8)? Like Spanish, Czech, French. For instance:

administrátoři (czech) administratori
français (french) francais
niñez (spanish) ninez etc.

I know I could do it manually with sed, but it's relatively time-consuming considering that I'm working on a lot of languages. I thought a program that could do just that might exist already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is called *Unicode decomposition* -- the reverse process of Unicode composition (where you combine a base character with a diacritic). There are a number of related SO questions using:

1. [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/javascript-remove-accents-in-strings)
2. [ActionScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587242/replacing-accents-w-their-counterparts-in-as3)
3. [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string)

which you can use as a starting point.

The Python repository has [`unicodedata.decomposition`](http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html) which returns a decomposed mapping.

Your system probably also has `iconv` and with [suitable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892897/why-can-iconv-convert-precomposed-form-but-not-decomposed-form-of-from-utf) Normalization it may get you there too!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using recode (at https://github.com/pinard/Recode/)?  It removes *accents* while trying hard to preserve information and also can produce xlat tables expressed in C.

```
$ cat testfile 
administrátoři (czech) administratori
français (french) francais
niñez (spanish) ninez etc.
$ LANG= recode -f UTF-8..texte <testfile 
administrtori (czech) administratori
franc,ais (french) francais
niez (spanish) ninez etc.
```